# setCenter() in Google Maps API to change center on map after click on button

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have three different locations. I'd like to change the shown location in my Google Map by click on a button.

I tried to use a Javascript function with setCenter(), but unfortunately it doesn't work. Has anyone an idea what might be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<script>

var map;
var marker;
var location1 = {lat: 45.123456, lng: 3.456789};
var location2 = {lat: 46.234567, lng: 4.567890};
var location3 = {lat: 47.345678, lng: 5.678901};

function initMap()
{
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: location1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location1,
        map: map,
        title: 'Click to zoom'
    });
}

function changeCenter(center) {
    map.setCenter([center]);
    marker.setPosition([center]);
}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

</script>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SOMEAPIKEY"
    async defer></script>

<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter('location1');">Location 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter('location2');">Location 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter('location3');">Location 3</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two typos in your code:

1. The `changeCenter(center)` function (since it just passes the argument `Map.setCenter()` and `Marker.setPosition()` needs to pass in the `google.maps.LatLngLiteral` directly, not inside an array:

```
function changeCenter(center) {
    map.setCenter([center]);
    marker.setPosition([center]);
}
```

Should be:

```
function changeCenter(center) {
    map.setCenter(center);
    marker.setPosition(center);
}
```

2. the calls to the function are passing in a string with the name of a variable, they need to pass in the variable itself:

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter('location1');">Location 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter('location2');">Location 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter('location3');">Location 3</button>
```

should be:

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location1);">Location 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location2);">Location 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location3);">Location 3</button>
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5eatfh42/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  var marker;
  var location1 = {
    lat: 45.123456,
    lng: 3.456789
  };
  var location2 = {
    lat: 46.234567,
    lng: 4.567890
  };
  var location3 = {
    lat: 47.345678,
    lng: 5.678901
  };

  function initMap() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: location1,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location1,
      map: map,
      title: 'Click to zoom'
    });
  }

  function changeCenter(center) {
      map.setCenter(center);
      marker.setPosition(center);
    }
    // google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>

<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location1);">Location 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location2);">Location 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location3);">Location 3</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! :)

Answer (score 0):

`setCenter` accepts only the following parameter types. Make sure you pass one of these types.

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-34, 151));
map.setCenter({lat: -34, lng: 151});
```

try `map.setCenter(center);` where `center` has no brackets `[]` and `changeCenter(location1)`

```
function changeCenter(center) {
    map.setCenter(center);
    marker.setPosition(center);
}
...
...
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location1);">Location 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location2);">Location 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:changeCenter(location3);">Location 3</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried the second version without brackets and it works fine for me:
map.setCenter(center);
..
..
changeCenter(location1);